# when to use apriori vs eclat association rules in R

Tags: r, data-mining, algorithms, association-rules, apriori

actually I have to extract from my data the frequent pattern in R.

The first algorithm I have used is `apriori` but reading some articles I have seen that also `eclat` is available in the same package.

My questions are:
 - Can we suppose that both algorithm retrive the same information ? For example when I set the same min support
 - Why if I use eclat the items are listed with the support information ?

The R codes I use are the following ones:

for APRIORI:

```
v_rules <- apriori(v_sold_tran, parameter = list(minlen=2,maxlen = 5,sup = 0.005, conf = 0.01, target="rules"))
```

for ECLAT:

```
itemsets <- eclat(v_sold_tran,parameter = list(supp = 0.005, maxlen = 5))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same minimum support, both algorithms *must* give the same result, or there is an error in their implementation. There is only one correct output.

I would assume that Apriori works better for many many many transactions, but fewer items, whereas Eclat probably works better for fewer transactions with more items. But that is just my guess. You'll have to figure this out yourself.

Answer (score 3):

ECLAT improves Apriori in the step of Extracting frequent itemsets. As you know Apriori has to scan the Database multiple times, but with ECLAT there is no need to scan the database for countig the support for k-itemsets (k>=1).
In R, apriori() could have as an output  the frequent itemsets or association rules. Althought eclat() has as an output just the frequent itemsets. You have after that use the command ruleInduction() to extract rules from those itemsets.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the association rule mining algorithms `apriori` and `eclat` in terms of execution time with `Adult` dataset:

```
library(arules)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
data("Adult")

dim(Adult)
# [1] 48842   115

params <- list(supp = 0.5, maxlen = 5)
tm <- microbenchmark(eclat(Adult, parameter = params),
                     apriori(Adult, parameter = params), 
                     times=100L)
autoplot(tm)
```

[image]

As can be seen, `apriori` on average has higher execution time when compared to `ecalt` for the same dataset with same parameters. The next code snippet shows the first 10 rules obtained by running both the algorithms.

```
rules <- apriori(Adult, parameter = params)
DATAFRAME(rules, separate = TRUE)[1:10,] # first 10 rules
#                          LHS                            RHS   support confidence  coverage      lift count
#1                          {}                   {race=White} 0.8550428  0.8550428 1.0000000 1.0000000 41762
#2                          {} {native-country=United-States} 0.8974243  0.8974243 1.0000000 1.0000000 43832
#3                          {}            {capital-gain=None} 0.9173867  0.9173867 1.0000000 1.0000000 44807
#4                          {}            {capital-loss=None} 0.9532779  0.9532779 1.0000000 1.0000000 46560
#5  {hours-per-week=Full-time} {native-country=United-States} 0.5179559  0.8852574 0.5850907 0.9864423 25298
#6  {hours-per-week=Full-time}            {capital-gain=None} 0.5435895  0.9290688 0.5850907 1.0127342 26550
#7  {hours-per-week=Full-time}            {capital-loss=None} 0.5606650  0.9582531 0.5850907 1.0052191 27384
#8                  {sex=Male}                   {race=White} 0.5883256  0.8800919 0.6684820 1.0292957 28735
#9                  {sex=Male} {native-country=United-States} 0.5983170  0.8950383 0.6684820 0.9973412 29223
#10                 {sex=Male}            {capital-gain=None} 0.6050735  0.9051455 0.6684820 0.9866565 29553

itemsets <- eclat(Adult, parameter = list(supp = 0.1, maxlen = 5))
rules <- ruleInduction(itemsets, confidence = .9)
DATAFRAME(rules, separate = TRUE)[1:10,] # first 10 rules
#                                                      LHS                            RHS   support confidence          lift
#2                                {relationship=Unmarried}            {capital-loss=None} 0.1019819  0.9719024   2  1.0195373
#4                                      {occupation=Sales}            {capital-loss=None} 0.1068343  0.9480378   4  0.9945030
#6                                      {occupation=Sales}            {capital-gain=None} 0.1030670  0.9146076   6  0.9969706
#8                                      {occupation=Sales} {native-country=United-States} 0.1039679  0.9226017   8  1.0280552
#12 {occupation=Adm-clerical,native-country=United-States}            {capital-loss=None} 0.1016338  0.9657588   12 1.0130925
#13            {occupation=Adm-clerical,capital-loss=None} {native-country=United-States} 0.1016338  0.9165436   13 1.0213046
#15            {occupation=Adm-clerical,capital-loss=None}            {capital-gain=None} 0.1038655  0.9366691   15 1.0210189
#16            {occupation=Adm-clerical,capital-gain=None}            {capital-loss=None} 0.1038655  0.9629841   16 1.0101819
#18                              {occupation=Adm-clerical}            {capital-loss=None} 0.1108882  0.9652468   18 1.0125555
#20                              {occupation=Adm-clerical}            {capital-gain=None} 0.1078580  0.9388701   20 1.0234180
```

The difference between the two algorithms / appropriate usecases can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167439/what-is-the-difference-between-apriori-and-eclat-algorithms).